# Locker puzzle in Python

Tags: python, programming-challenge, unit-testing

> (Game: locker puzzle) A school has 100 lockers and 100 students. All
>   lockers are closed on the first day of school. As the students enter,
>   the first student, denoted S1, opens every locker. Then the second
>   student, S2, begins with the second locker, denoted L2, and closes
>   every other locker. Student S3 begins with the third locker and
>   changes every third locker (closes it if it was open, and opens it if
>   it was closed). Student S4 begins with locker L4 and changes every
>   fourth locker. Student S5 starts with L5 and changes every fifth
>   locker, and so on, until student S100 changes L100.
>
> After all the students have passed through the building and changed
>   the lockers, which lockers are open? Write a program to find your
>   answer.

```
import doctest

def invert_multiples(bools, n):
    """
    Inverts all the items at index n*a

    >>> invert_multiples([True, True, True, True], 2)
    [False, True, False, True]
    """
    return [not bool_ if index % n == 0 else bool_
                      for index, bool_ in enumerate(bools)
                      ]

def invert_all_multiples(bools, nums):
    """
    Subsequentially inverts all the items that are
    multiples of each num. 

    >>> doors = invert_all_multiples([True]*100, range(1,101))
    >>> [i[0] for i in enumerate(doors) if not i[1]]
    [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
    """
    for num in nums:
        bools = invert_multiples(bools, num)
    return bools

if __name__ == "__main__":
    doctest.testmod()
```

I am not interested in the square numbers trick/optimization.

Comment: "I am not interested in the square numbers trick/optimization." — Why not?

Comment: @GarethRees because I already know that in the end only the perfect squared doors remain open, but coding that would not be interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of thing is suited to `numpy` arrays.  You can invert a boolean numpy array using `~arr`, which is an element-by-element `not` operation.  You can do this to a slice by `arr[start:stop:step] = ~arr[start:stop:step]`, or in your case where you are going to the end `arr[start::step] = ~arr[start::step]`.  It is also an in-place operation, thus avoiding unnecessary copies.

So a direct translation of your code to numpy would be like so:

```
import numpy as np

def invert_multiples(bools, n):
    """
    Inverts all the items at index n*a

    >>> invert_multiples([True, True, True, True], 2)
    [False, True, False, True]
    """
    bools[num::num+1] = ~bools[num::num+1]

def invert_all_multiples(bools, nums):
    """
    Subsequentially inverts all the items that are
    multiples of each num. 

    >>> doors = invert_all_multiples([True]*100, range(1,101))
    >>> [i[0] for i in enumerate(doors) if not i[1]]
    [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
    """
    bools = np.array(bools)
    for num in nums:
        invert_multiples(bools, num)
    return bools.tolist()
```

If you are able to avoid lists, a simpler version of the stated problem is:

```
nmax = 100
lockers = np.zeros(nmax, dtype='bool')
for n in range(nmax):
    lockers[n::n+1] = ~lockers[n::n+1]
res = np.flatnonzero(lockers)  # add one to get one-based indexing
```

Comment: Sorry, the problem is now fixed

Comment: Sorry, somehow misread the question as "how many are open".  Fixed now.

Comment: *sigh*, not doing very well here, sorry.  Fixed.

Comment: Okay, this version should work